# CakePHP associating Users with one City

Tags: cakephp, associations, has-one, database-relations

I have a User table and a table for the cities, which I want to associate with each other. As you guess, a City can have multiple Users but one User can only be linked to one city.

I really don't know how to set my tables up. When I try $hasMany relation for the City and $hasOne for my User then I am getting an error, because the client_id field cannot be found in my cities table. My cities table is going to be fixed: no one will ever change the table. I just want to store some information about a city in this table.

**Edit:** Here are my tables and my models (kept simple):

```
clients { id, firstname, lastname, city_id }
cities { id, name, some_other_data }
```

And here are my models:

```
// User
class Client extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
        'City'
    );
}

// City
class City extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'cities';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Client'
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the models (User and City if you have it), and you table's columns/names ?

Comment: You have `User` and `City` table, but there supposed to be `users` and `cities`... Or rather `clients` and `cities` according to what I'm seeing in you models

Comment: Thats not the matter. I followed CakePHP's naming conventions. My User Model can access the data. But I cant get the '$hasOne city' thing work, because when I set it I get this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'City.client_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 2):

You need to reverse the relation; A Client 'belongsTo' a city. (I know, this *sounds* illogical);

```
// User
class Client extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'City'
    );
}

// City
class City extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'cities';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Client'
    );
}
```

Your clients-table should contain a `city_id` field to make this work properly (just looked at your table-definition and it's already there, so just changing the Client-model should make it work for you).

Answer (score 1):

may be it will not work we have to specify foreignkey

```
    // User
class Client extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'City'=> array(
        'className' => 'City',
        'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
     ) ,
    );
}
// City
class City extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'cities';

public $hasMany = array(
    'Client' => array(
        'className' => 'Client',
        'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
     ) ,
  ); 
}
```

Comment: This should not be the problem, the OP has properly used the CakePHP conventions, so adding ClassName and foreignKey is *not* nescessary